# How to make a option in search to be always visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made an search bar using html, css and javascript and it is working perfectly but I want the answers to be shown when the user starts typing, not before. And I also want to add one option in it which is always shown whether it matches the result or not.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 7px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#tools">Cyber Warriors YouTube Channel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "And I also want to add one option in it which is always shown whether it matches the result or not" what does it mean?

Comment: means like if someone searches anything,  like if anyone searches 'computer' and this option is not available or there is no result then an option of 'more' is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove onclick from input and  add a class "fixed-input" on the value you wanted to be fixed

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function hideOptions() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}

function showOptions() {
  hideOptions();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if( input.value === ''){
      hideOptions();
      return false;
  }
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else if(a[i].classList.contains('fixed-input') === true) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  showOptions();
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 7px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input type="text" class="dropbtn" placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support" class="fixed-input">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    <a href="#tools">Cyber Warriors YouTube Channel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Please try to remove onclick event and code to show dropdown inside onkeyup event.
For better understanding see the attached code snippet.
```

```js
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  if (filter.length > 0) {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.add("show");
  } else {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
  }
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValue.toLowerCase() === 'more') {
      a[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;    
} 
.dropbtn {
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}
#myInput:focus {    
  outline: 7px solid #ddd;
}
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {     
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <input type="text" class="dropbtn"  placeholder="Search Here..." id="myInput" onInput="filterFunction()">
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#base">Base</a>
        <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
        <a href="#support">Support</a>
        <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
        <a href="#tools">Cyber Warriors YouTube Channel</a>
        <a href="#tools">More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it worked and was perfect. Thank you very much.